# How to Set Alert message when the drug is expiry with in 6 months ago using Codeigniter 2.2.6

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-2

I tried to set a alert message on the userpage that the drug is going to expired with in the 6 months compare `expiry_date` column with present date(Current server time ) and I need auto alert message as "Your Drug Is Going Expiry Within 6 Months"

Code:

```
<?php 
  foreach($passport as $result) {
    $sixtyDays = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-60 days'));
    //print_r($sixtyDays);exit;

    $dbDate = $result->passport_expiry;
    //print_r($dbDate);exit;

    if (strtotime($dbDate) > strtotime('-30 days')) {
      echo "your passport is going to expiry within 6 months";
    } else{
      echo "your passport is  not going to expiry within 6 months"  ?>
    }  
 }
?>
```

But still am confused and not getting the logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo '<script language="javascript">';
          echo 'alert("message successfully sent")';
          echo '</script>';
```

try using this

Comment: hi rahul could please see the above things if my  drug  expiry is going before 6 months i need a alert.

Comment: firstly the alert tag works in javascripts  to show it in php you need to call the javascript my suggestion i that for your current functionalilty kindly do that with js or use the alert in php as the code i gave. you wana get a  alert in if part??